# Find the image of this Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, orthogonality

**The Question:**

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex inner product space.

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ with basis $\{ e_1,\dots,e_k\}$.

Let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation defined by

$$T(v) = \langle v,e_1 \rangle e_1+\langle v,e_2 \rangle e_2+ \cdots + \langle v,e_k \rangle e_k$$

Show that the Image of $T$ is $W$, $\;$ i.e. $\text{Im}(T) = W$.

---

**My Attempt:**

Showing one direction of the inclusion is easy:

\begin{align}
w \in \text{Im}(T) & \implies \exists \; v \in V \,|\, T(v) = w \\
& \implies w = T(v) = \langle v,e_1 \rangle e_1+\langle v,e_2 \rangle e_2+ \cdots + \langle v,e_k \rangle e_k \\
& \implies w \in \text{span} \{e_1,\dots,e_k\} \\
& \implies w \in W
\end{align}

But I don't know how to show the converse.

I suppose that it suffices to show that $\exists \; v_i \in V \,|\, T(v_i)=e_i$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$, but when I tried to construct such $v_i$ it became really messy.

I have also considered Gram-Schimdt but it doesn't seem to help.

Any hints?

Comment: Maybe try and show that the restriction of $T$ to $W\subset V$, i.e. $T|_W:W \to W$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Aren't you just restating what I have to prove...?

Comment: Well, I guess you can read my comment that way. My point is: Show that $T|_W$ is one-to-one, and then since $W$ is finite-dimensional, then $T|_W$ is automatically an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Because $V$ is finite dimensional, it suffices to show that $\ker T|_{W} = \{0\}$.

With that in mind: if $T(v) = 0$, then we can deduce that $\langle v,e_k \rangle = 0$ for $k = 1,\dots,n$.  Using the fact that $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is a basis and the linearity of our inner product, we can show that this implies that $\langle v,v \rangle = 0$, which is to say that $v = 0$.

Comment: I proceeded to reason that because $T|_W(v) = 0 \iff v=0$ and that $\text{Im}(T)\subset W$, it follows that $T|_W : W\rightarrow W$ is a bijection, and hence $\text{Im}(T) = W$.

Comment: Does that sound right?

Comment: @glowstonetrees that's right.